# MIX dapp IDE - how to run your dapp after deployment, error web3 is not defined

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, dapps, contract-deployment, mix

I managed to run a personal test chain. I deploy the Sample contract and everything is ok. Transactions included.
Now how can I run the dapp?
I go to the local package folder inside www I open the index.html file but

> I get the error : web3 is not defined

Where are the web libraries defined? inside the node? Am I running the node in a wrong way?

```
geth --identity "Computer" --genesis myChain/myChainGenesys.json --rpc --rpcport "8000" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "myChain" --port "30303" --nodiscover --ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --autodag --networkid 666666666 --nat "any" --unlock 0 console
```

This works for mining and deployment, does it work to play with the deployed app?

is the app here?

```
file:///home/computer/ttt/package//www/
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Show the source code of your `index.html`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/yHC3uDp7 it is the very basic example you find in Mix IDE, I didn't touch anything. I deployed and maybe I simply don't know how to run it. No instructions around.

Comment: deployment.js http://pastebin.com/knWYwfgk

Comment: contract.sol http://pastebin.com/RAEmLwbE

Comment: These 3 files are generated by `mix` ?

Comment: yes. deployment.js is generated after I deploy and package. Now I deployed them on the main net. contract address : 0xa8881036f25364c2ac6c4269f6b068414b795a99 so the contract is really deployed, I can find it using the blockchain explorer. May be the question isn't precise, since I am not expert. How to expose the contract to the world? do I simply run a node? How to tell the node to expose that contract? Or... is the html+js asking the node to expose that specific contract?

Comment: have you installed web3.js ? lol

Comment: where should I install it? in the computer or in the browser? can you please drive me to some instructions online? thanks

Comment: I would like to visit the dapp via browser, like a web site. So I point the browser to the local package generated by Mix , but the dapp doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should have to install `Web3.js` before running your Dapp in Mix.

From [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/master#installation):

> **Installation**
>
> **Node.js**
>
> ```
> npm install web3
> ```
>
> **Meteor.js**
>
> ```
> meteor add ethereum:web3
> ```
>
> **As Browser module**
>
> **Bower**
>
> ```
> bower install web3
> ```
>
> **Component**
>
> ```
> component install ethereum/web3.js
> ```
>
> Include `ethereum.min.js` in your html file. (not required for the
>   meteor package)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, this helps. But I want to run the dapp with the browser. The dapp works perfectly inside Mix. I need to run it with the browser. The error I get comes from the browser. sorry I explained myself in a bad way. I have geth + html/js + deployed-dapp. I want to go there with the browser. Isn't possible? How can a final user visit my web3 html page? do they have to install other things? I would like them to visit with browser, with geth open in background.

Comment: Web3 is the js client (the one you use to show your content in the browser). Geth is not needed for it. You just have to be sure that your browser app can use the web3 module. You can do it just making a `truffle deploy` in your server and that will deploy the contracts and the web app

Comment: At the moment I try to understand Meteor. I will have a look to truffle too. thanks for the infos. very precious. do you know any example of dapp made with truffle?

Comment: When you do `truffle init` you get an example dapp :)

Comment: Find the official documentation of Truffle here : http://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ . Follow it and you will get a running Dapp example. @Max